# Installing CRM Rollup 3 to Ms CRM 2013 on-premise

Tags: rollup, servicepacks

I want to install the latest service pack for CRM 2013 (Rollup 3), shall we install Rollup 1 followed by Rollup 2, and then Rollup 3? Or can we install Rollup 3 directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install RU3 without installing the others, as RUs are typically cumulative.

**From [Update Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699658(v=crm.6).aspx):**

> **Are update rollups cumulative?**
>
> *Yes, update rollups are typically cumulative. This means that the problems that are fixed in an update rollup are also fixed in later update rollups. For example, Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Update Rollup 2 contains all the fixes and feature improvements that are included in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Update Rollup 1.*

**A note of caution**: you don't mention if you've installed SP1 or not, and the latest rollout that was released last week is targeted at 2013SP1; there was also a RU3 that was released last year prior to SP1's release - they reset the Rollup count with each Service Pack or Major Release.

To verify, check your version number (click the gear icon in the upper right corner and then click "about"). The number tends to follow the "Major.SP.RU.xxxx" approach, so if you're 6.1.x.xxxx, you have SP1, if you're 6.0.x.xxxx, you probably don't.

**From the [Surviving CRM](http://survivingcrm.com/2014/07/update-rollups-service-packs-major-releases/) blog:**

> Starting with CRM 2013, the version numbering scheme follows a pattern like this (notice the bold numbers):
>
> - Major Release
>
>   - Name: Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013
>   - Version number: **6**.0.0.xxxx
> - Service Pack:
>
>   - Name: Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Service Pack 1
>   - Version number: 6.**1**.0.xxxx
> - Update Rollup:
>
>   - Name: Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Update Rollup 1
>   - Version number: 6.0.**1**.xxxx